# Installed Luximono is not working

Tags: fonts, typewriter

I am using MacTex-2011 on a mac 10.7. Recently, I have installed luximono using getnonfreefonts. Everything went ok, but when I was compiling the document (pdfLaTeX) with the packages:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage{luximono}
```

luximono was not recognized, i.e. LaTeX used the standard font. Any ideas how to get it working?

Comment: Stupid question: If you want Luximono as the *standard* text font, have you tried `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\ttdefault}`?

Comment: what does `kpsewhich luximono.sty` say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luxi Mono is a monotype font and not enabled by default. If you want to use it change the default tt font family, use `\ttfamily` or `\texttt{..}`.

By the way: it is not a good idea to set the complete document in a monotype font.

Comment: What is the reason for avoiding monotype fonts for the complete document?

Comment: compare it with another font ... However, if one has to submit an article to a journal, it may make sense to use a monotype font, counting charcters is easier.

Comment: Oh! I thought you meant Monotype Corp. Yes, I can obviously see why a monospaced font is a bad idea!